# How to insert multiple rows and colums to dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with exchange rate data. I want to insert the base currency(Norwegian Krone) for the entire daterange(from min Date to max Date) at value 1 in Units.

Tried to merge dataframes, but no luck with my skills. 
The data is required for further computation for another task.

```
       Currency         Date      Rate  UoM
0   Swedish krona   2016-01-05  1.0395  Hundreds
1   Swedish krona   2016-01-06  1.0422  Hundreds
2   Swedish krona   2016-01-07  1.0452  Hundreds
3   Swedish krona   2016-01-08  1.0450  Hundreds
4   Swedish krona   2016-01-11  1.0437  Hundreds
5   Swedish krona   2016-01-12  1.0422  Hundreds
6   Swedish krona   2016-01-13  1.0338  Hundreds
7   Swedish krona   2016-01-14  1.0347  Hundreds
8   Swedish krona   2016-01-15  1.0279  Hundreds
9   Swedish krona   2016-01-18  1.0371  Hundreds
... ... ... ... ...
3313    US dollar   2019-03-15  8.5674  Units
3314    US dollar   2019-03-18  8.5223  Units
3315    US dollar   2019-03-19  8.5178  Units
3316    US dollar   2019-03-20  8.5358  Units
3317    US dollar   2019-03-21  8.4463  Units
3318    US dollar   2019-03-22  8.5315  Units
3319    US dollar   2019-03-25  8.5289  Units
```

The expected output is new rows to the dataframe i.e.

```
3320    Norwegian krone 2016-01-06  1   Units
3321    Norwegian krone 2016-01-07  1   Units
3322    Norwegian krone 2016-01-08  1   Units
3323    Norwegian krone 2016-01-11  1   Units
... ... ... ... ...
XXXX    Norwegian krone 2019-03-21  1   Units
XXXX    Norwegian krone 2019-03-22  1   Units
XXXX    Norwegian krone 2019-03-25  1   Units
```

Comment: You need concat not merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to obtain a range of dates that have holes in it like the source data and then to efficiently construct the repeating rows for the purpose of appending and then sorting.  When constructing a dataframe, a single dictionary may be used to fill out the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""Currency,Date,Rate,UoM
Swedish krona,2016-01-05,1.0395,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-06,1.0422,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-07,1.0452,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-08,1.0450,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-11,1.0437,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-12,1.0422,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-13,1.0338,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-14,1.0347,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-15,1.0279,Hundreds
Swedish krona,2016-01-18,1.0371,Hundreds
US dollar,2019-03-15,8.5674,Units
US dollar,2019-03-18,8.5223,Units
US dollar,2019-03-19,8.5178,Units
US dollar,2019-03-20,8.5358,Units
US dollar,2019-03-21,8.4463,Units
US dollar,2019-03-22,8.5315,Units
US dollar,2019-03-25,8.5289,Units""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df = df.set_index(['Date'])
date_range = df.index.values
nk_df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range, data={'Currency':'Norwegian krone', 'Rate':1, 'UoM':'Units'})
df = pd.concat([df, nk_df])
print(df.sort_index().head(10))
```

produces

```
0.24.2
                   Currency    Rate       UoM
2016-01-05    Swedish krona  1.0395  Hundreds
2016-01-05  Norwegian krone  1.0000     Units
2016-01-06    Swedish krona  1.0422  Hundreds
2016-01-06  Norwegian krone  1.0000     Units
2016-01-07  Norwegian krone  1.0000     Units
2016-01-07    Swedish krona  1.0452  Hundreds
2016-01-08    Swedish krona  1.0450  Hundreds
2016-01-08  Norwegian krone  1.0000     Units
2016-01-11  Norwegian krone  1.0000     Units
2016-01-11    Swedish krona  1.0437  Hundreds
```

Comment: Great, solved my problem. I was unaware of the concat function.